# How to view File Structure of a class in IntelliJ without opening the actual class file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After 15 years on Eclipse, I'm slowing migrating to IntelliJ 2017 and trying to find equivalent ways of working.  In Eclipse, I am able to press 'F4' on any member of my current class and see the structure of the highlighted member (including all it's member and methods) in the 'Hierarchy' view.

In IntelliJ I found the 'Alt-7' Structure view, but that only seems to show me the Structure of the currently opened class in the editor.  Is there any way to see the structure of a highlighted/selected member instead (including it's private/public members & methods)?

For example:

```
public class CustomProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        ....
        ....

    }
}
```

In Eclipse, I would be able to highlight `TokenStore` or `HashMap`, press F4 and see the hierarchy of TokenStore (or HashMap) even though my current editor is still CustomProvider.

Is there an equivalent way available in IntelliJ (ie: without needing to open the TokenStore class) to view a selected class hierarchy (and it's members/methods) without needing to open the targeted class in the editor?  Otherwise put, I would like to be able to view the Structure (Alt-7) of `TokenStore` while editing the `CustomProvider`.

Comment: with `crtl+shift+A ` you can search everything, if you type `hierarchy` or `call` you should be able to see the options for the "call hierarchy" and "class hierarchy" equivalents in intellij

Comment: Ctrl + F12 shows a Structure Popup of the already opened Class

Comment: @Paizo Thanks - but the class hierarchy doesn't show me the member fields or methods.  I can only see the actual class hierarchy.  I've updated my question to be less misleading, b/c I'm actually looking to see the complete structure of the class (ie: members & methods included)

Comment: @D.Braun I'm specially looking for the class that I've highlighted - not the class that is opened in my editor.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted to close as unclear; please specify what is unclear so I can add clarity to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this feature is not available at the moment. You can [vote for this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99339).

Comment: Wow... I can't believe this has been an open request since 2013!  For me, it is part of my basic workflow.  Is there some other approach I can use in IntelliJ to have a similar experience?  Ie: see the API/structure of a class without opening the file in the editor?